# Windows 8 version of iStat Menus or System Load Indicator

Tags: macos, ubuntu, windows-8, performance-monitor

I just switched back to Windows 8 from Ubuntu and Mac environment. Since using both UNIX platforms, I relied much information about the system status (CPU, Memory, Network, Activity, etc.) provided by these two applications:

- Mac OS -> [iStatMenu](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)
- Ubuntu -> [System Load Indicator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/indicator-multiload/)

I was wondering if there's a similar software available for Windows 8/8.1 users to indicate system status on the taskbar? I've been searching around though [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/) can provide this feature yet it's only limited on desktop.